# How can I view raw SOAP information sent out on the wire using WCF Trace Viewer?

Tags: .net, wcf, logging, soap, fiddler

I am troubleshooting message encryption of soap WCF messages.

Using Fiddler, I can see the raw messages, complete with CipherData/CipherValue XML elements in the SOAP body.

I have configured message logging using the following config:

```
<diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="true">
  <messageLogging
       logEntireMessage="true"
       logMalformedMessages="true"
       logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
       logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
       maxMessagesToLog="3000"
       maxSizeOfMessageToLog="100000"/>
</diagnostics>
```

Now when I open the resulting log XML file, I can only see the unencrypted SOAP messages, the CipherData/CipherValue elements are nowhere to be found.

It looks like the WCF logging is done at a point in the stack where the message has not yet been encrypted.

Is there a way to configure WCF logging so that I can see the messages after encryption?

BTW, the reason why I want to see the encrypted version of the message in the WCF trace file is that I am not able to use Fiddler to troubleshoot on the production environment.

Answer (score 3):

Set up your `system.diagnostics` configuration like this.

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net" tracemode="includehex" maxdatasize="1024">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
      <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose"/>
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="System.Net" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="network.log"/>
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

That should give you more detail. For more info see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

WCF decodes the encryption to make it human readable, I don’t know if WFC could be configured to not to do the decryption but if you use Wireshark you will see what will goes on wire exactly since it uses Winpcap.

You need to download and install Winpcap and then install WireShark. It will do the job for you but
If you need much more control on what is transferring on wire, here it is a complete sample that uses WinPcap to sniff wire packets.

http://www.binarytides.com/code-packet-sniffer-c-winpcap/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to hookup BeforeSendReply of IDispatchMessageInspector and log message there, that's the last point before the message goes in network, not sure but at this point the message should be encrypted, more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.beforesendreply%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If code change is not an option then wireshark is your best bet but usually infra guys are reluctatnt in putting such a software on production servers.